# How to move customer from one website to another in Magento?

Tags: magento, web, migration

I have 2 websites set up in Magento, each has one store in it. Each website has its own customer accounts. Now, I need to shutdown one website, and migrate all customer accounts from website A to website B, so that customers from website A's store can login to website B's store. What do I need to do to accomplish this? What to do if a customer has account on both website A's store and Website B's store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's just an idea. I've never tried this myself before and this is usually not the way things should be done. So backup your database or setup a test installation where you try this first and follow the below steps:

1) Find out the old website id and the new one where the customer have to be added

2) open your database with a MySQL Client or PhpMyAdmin

3) go to table 'customer_entity' and open the content

4) change one of the customer entries from old website id to new website id

If this works, you could write an sql update that changes all the website ids in that table.
You can also check if that customer account (e-mail address) exists in website B or not for each entry.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/update.html

The better way this should be done:
Writing a little Magento Module with some code that reads out all the customer data from website A and writes it into website B.
But this needs some Magento Development Skills. If you're interested in a professional solution, feel free to contact.

cheers

edit: could make sense to change the store_id value as well

Comment: Besides the website id and store id, is there any other fields that determines or related to which website and store a customer belongs to?

Comment: While changing the `website_id` in the main customer table will reassign the customer account, any of its associated data, like website-specific rewards or sales, will not carry over.

Answer (score 14):

Wanna try a brutal idea?? It's inside my head and this is maybe a *glitch* of Magento.

1. Go to your customer that wanted the store to be changed.
2. Open your console on browser (firebug or something)
   [image]
3. Find the html tag

> ```
> <select id="_accountwebsite_id" name="account[website_id]" class=" required-entry required-entry select" disabled="disabled">
> <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
> <option value="0">Admin</option>
> <option value="1" selected="selected">Main Website</option>
> </select>
> ```

4. remove the disabled="disabled" and add the value of option to id that your store want.

> ```
> <select id="_accountwebsite_id" name="account[website_id]" class=" required-entry required-entry select">
> <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
> <option value="0">Admin</option>
> <option value="0" selected="selected">Main Website</option>
> </select>
> ```

5. And Done. your customer store has been changed.
   [image]

> ***Remember this is the brutal and not recommended idea. LOL***

Comment: Yeah it works, thanks for that. Gives a blank page, but upon going back to admin customer view, the website was changed. The blank page is probably the reason it's grayed out :D

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews My pleasure . . . it's Magento's Cheat :D

Answer (score 5):

Theres another, simpler way that just comes into my mind. Never tried this either.
Go to System->Import/Export in your Admin and export your customers in a CSV file.
Open this file with OpenOffice or LibreOffice, change the website and store code values and then try to import it again.

Answer (score 3):

**login admin then 

go to system ->import/export ->export 

select entity type as "customers"  

click on continue button and save csv file on local pc 

now you can use this browse csv to import customers on other website with "import" option(shows in snapshot)**

*screenshot guide*
[image]